# ECMAScript class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following code which when the web page loads should print the car make and current speed to the console. Nothing is printed to the console. If I put the new object declaration inside a function it does print either.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="application/ecmascript;version=6">

class Car {
    constructor(make) {
    this.make = make;
    this.currentSpeed = 20;
    }

    printCurrentSpeed(){

    console.log(this.make + 'is going ' + this.currentSpeed + 'kmh.');
    }

}

var stang = new Car('Mustang');
stang.printCurrentSpeed();

</script>

    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class keyword is es6. Currently, it is only available in stable browsers [Chrome 42](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes).

Your code can work in Chrome 42 with two modifications:

1) The browser will ignore any script types it does not understand. Chrome doesn't appear to run any code inside of `<script type="application/ecmascript;version=6"></script>`. You should remove the type.

2) Block scoped declarations (`let`, `const` `class`) are only available in strict mode. You need to explicitly opt in:  `'use strict';`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
'use strict';
class Car {
    constructor(make) {
    this.make = make;
    this.currentSpeed = 20;
    }

    printCurrentSpeed(){

    console.log(this.make + 'is going ' + this.currentSpeed + 'kmh.');
    }

}

var stang = new Car('Mustang');
stang.printCurrentSpeed();

</script>

    <title>
    </title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Nathanael. That works. I would like to get it functioning with the "application/ecmascript" tag however. Chrome 42 is a version below the one I have installed.

Comment: `<script type="application/ecmascript"></script>` is fine, [but Chrome will choke on `application/ecmascript;version=6`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script). You could try `application/ecmascript;version=1.8` in Nightly Versions of Firefox. Basically until you 100% of your targeted browsers use the `class` syntax, there is no way to make this work without transpiling.

Answer (score 2):

ES2015 (ex-ES6) classes are not yet natively supported by currently available browsers. If you want to use them, you will have to use what we call a transpiler : a program which will automatically convert your ES2015 source code into ES5, so that current browsers can run it.

The most famous one is currently [Babel](https://babeljs.io/). Another one is [Traceur](https://github.com/google/traceur-compiler/) (by Google). Both are good.

Note that you don't *have* to use ES2015 to actually have classes. ES2015 classes are just a syntaxic sugar around what we call the prototype. Here is your example without the `class` keyword:

```
function Car(make) {
    this.make = make;
    this.currentSpeed = 20;
}

Car.prototype.printCurrentSpeed = function() {
    console.log(this.make + 'is going ' + this.currentSpeed + 'kmh.');
};

var stang = new Car('Mustang');
stang.printCurrentSpeed();
```

Comment: Chrome 43, 44 and 45 does not support class, but Firefox 39+ might support it. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/

Comment: That seems like a lot of work. Can I use an earlier version of ECMAS that my code will work in?

Comment: @leesider You can use regular ES5 code, which is now widely available. That means no classes, no imports, no fat arrows, though.

Comment: I upgraded Firefox today and it downloaded 38.05.Says it is up to date.

Comment: Thanks Mael but I need to use a class

Comment: @leesider Classes are mainly syntaxic sugars around what we call the "prototype". Check the [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript) for more information. I added an example in my answer.